# Swagger single interactive html

Tags: documentation, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to make a single html with the try out button. The 
swagger-code gen nor the swagger-ui gives me that result. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: 'Single HTML with the "try out" button' is Swagger UI. How exactly does it not work for you?

Comment: I need a single html what I can use as an attachment :)

Comment: Uhm... zip Swagger UI? It's 1 HTML + 1 CSS + 2 .js + your spec.

Comment: Nope.. that is not an option.. I need one big messy html ^_^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try changing [Swagger UI](http://petstore.swagger.io) into "one big messy HTML file" as follows:

1. Download Swagger UI ([link to the latest master](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/master.zip)).
2. Go to the `dist` folder.
3. Edit `index.html` as follows:

   - Delete `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" >` and paste the contents of the `swagger-ui.css` file into the `<style>` element.
   - Replace

     ```
     <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
     <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
     ```

     with a `<script>...</script>` element containing the code from `swagger-ui-bundle.js` and `swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js`.
   - Replace

     ```
     url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
     ```

     with the `spec` parameter containing your API spec in the JSON format, like so:

     ```
     spec: {
       "swagger": "2.0",
       "info": ...,
       "paths": ...
     },
     ```

     If your spec is YAML, convert it to JSON first, e.g. using https://www.json2yaml.com.
   - Remove the favicons: `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-...`

Now `index.html` can be used as a standalone file.

Comment: Nowadays, the initialization of `SwaggerUIBundle` (with "url") is in "swagger-initializer.js", so you need to copy in that one too. Otherwise, the instructions still work.