# Downloading swagger-documentation in the same style as displayed

Tags: swagger-editor

I'm using the swagger-editor docker.

It produces, in the right column, a beautiful and functional interactive version of the documentation I'm writing in the right column.

I am trying to export such documentation but to no luck.

Is it possible to export an interactive, stand alone, documentation looking and working as the one shown in the right column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-side panel of Swagger Editor is [**Swagger UI**](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/). You can download Swagger UI assets and host them on your own website.

1. Download (or clone) the Swagger UI repository:
   https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui
2. Take the `dist` folder - it contains the static assets.
3. Put your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file to the `dist` folder.
4. In the `dist\index.html` file, change the `url` parameter to point to your YAML/JSON file:

   ```js
         const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
           url: "myapi.yaml",  // <----
   ```
5. Put the files from the `dist` folder on your web server.

It's also possible to [embed Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46237255/113116) into your existing web page, e.g. if you want to have your custom branded header and footer.

See also:

- [Is it possible to get an offline version of Swagger documentation for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50137466/113116)
- [Swagger UI single interactive HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45567723/113116)